# JS/AJAX Auto submit form: Disabling enter key to prevent page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a function that will submit with ajax and without the help of a button click. But I am currently undergoing two issues which with trial and error haven't found plausible solutions:

First is there any way I can disable the enter button click(this causes the whole page to refresh)?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pXA6U/3/) basic example in how the JS function works

Second, It feels like I am going the roundabout way to display what has been posted. How can I change this part of the function `$('#special').html('<p>' +  $('#resultval', result).html() + '</p>');` to have it POST just inside a div called `#special` without the need of `span or <p> #resultval`?

Everytime i echo through php I have to do set it like this to display a result: `<div id="special"><span id="resultval">This is the result.</span></div>`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var timer = null; 
     var dataString;   
     function submitForm(){
       $.ajax({ type: "POST",
                url: "posting.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(result){

                   $('#special').html('<p>' +  $('#resultval', result).html() + '</p>');

                }

       });
       return false;
     }
     $('#ytinput').on('keyup', function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
        var name = $("#ytinput").val();
        dataString = 'name='+ name;
     });
     }); 

</script>
```

Comment: Can you make posting.php return JSON instead of html?  It's easier to parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var timer = null; 
 var dataString;   
 function submitForm(event){// the function call on click or on submit onclick=submitForm(event);

    event.preventDefault(); //to prevent enter key
   $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "posting.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(result){

               $('#special').text(result); //you can use text() or html() only

            }

   });
   return false;
 }
 $('#ytinput').on('keyup', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(submitForm, 050);
    var name = $("#ytinput").val();
    dataString = 'name='+ name;
 });
 });
```